# Break lines in PHP are not working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to formate the email using line breaks, so it looks like:

```
Name:
Email:
Message:
```

I added the `\r\n` but it did nothing, then I tried and added `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";` thinking that I need to tell it that this is HTML and that did nothing as well.

What I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
      ob_start();

      if(isset($_POST['name'])
      && isset($_POST['email'])
      && isset($_POST['message'])
      && isset($_POST['token'])){

         if($_SESSION['token'] != $_POST['token']){
            $response = "0";
         } else {
            $_SESSION['token'] = "";
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            $to = "support@loaidesign.co.uk";
            $subject = "New Message From: $name";
            $message = "Name: $name\r\n
                        Email: $email\r\n\r\n
                        Message: $message";

            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: '.$email . "\r\n";
            $mailed = ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) );

            if( isset($_POST['ajax']))$response = ($mailed) ? "1" :
            "0"; else $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" :
            "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";
            echo $response;
         }

      } else {
         echo "Form data error!";
      }

      ob_flush();
      die();
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try with `<br/>` HTML tags because you have specified `text/html` content type:

```
$message = "Name: $name<br/>
            Email: $email<br/><br/>
            Message: $message";
```

Comment: Just to add on to hsz's answer, you are using carriage returns and new lines `\r\n`, which only work in text format. In HTML formatted email, you must use HTML.

Comment: How did I really miss this?! Thank you it worked. Does that mean I can actually used html and css elements safely on there?

Comment: Also what is the default element of $name for example? is it <p>?

Comment: @Loai You can use HTML and CSS in your message.

Answer (score 4):

To display line-break in html, you have to use `<br/>` (or use `<pre></pre>` tags, if you really care about using `\r\n`).

Notice you can use the php constant `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 0):

change "\r\n" to html new line tag: [br](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) - should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple text and not using `text/html` try:

```
$message = "Name: $name\r\n".
           "Email: $email\r\n\r\n".
           "Message: $message";
```